# Extract single value by indexing a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am calling a row from a pandas dataframe as

```
row = df.iloc[[i]]
customer.customer_id = row['billing_city']
```

When I then call `customer.billing_city I get an output like

```
4    Brooklyn
Name: billing_address_city, dtype: object
```

I would like to just have

```
Booklyn
```

for pursposes of creating objects and such

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.iat` to access a single item.

```
df.iat[i, df.columns.get_loc('billing_city')]
```

Uses `iat` for the same reason you've used `iloc`. If your indexes are integeral, it won't matter, and you could use `df.at` instead.

---

There's also `loc` + `item`.

```
df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('billing_city')].item()
```

Comment: If we were truthful, all these Pandas questions have a dup somewhere. The problem is `[python]` and `[pandas]` have degenerated somewhat to accept these as the norm. We need more "why is this..." type questions to keep these tags interesting.

Comment: @jpp Amen to that. I don't bother looking for dupes half the time because they have the absolute worst naming sense. It'd be easier to answer one yourself, edit the title to be easily searchable, and then start closing future questions as duplicates of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
res = df.at[i, 'billing_city']
```

Assumes your dataframe is indexed by an integer range; if this isn't the case, you can use `df.reset_index()` prior to using this method.